# What is the difference between "body count" and "death toll"?

Tags: meaning, differences

Not much more to explain, I guess. It seems that "death toll" is "official", while "body count" is "casual" or maybe "military". But I'm not certain.

Comment: You can't always count the number of dead, as they might be missing, obliterated beyond recognition, stuck at the bottom of the sea etc. So the death toll—those known to be dead—might differ significantly from the actual body count.

Comment: So what you say is that if there were 9 people on the ship and the ship sank and only 4 bodies were trieved then we have "body count = 4" and "death toll = 9", more or less? This would be pretty clear.

Comment: That's certainly my take on it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very simple terms, *body count* is a military term used for:"[the number of soldiers killed in a specific period or in a particular military action](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/body-count)". *Death toll* is a more general term used for:"[the ​number of ​people who ​die because of an ​event such as a ​war or an ​accident](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/death-toll)"

Comment: Ok, I can live with that, although I'm not certain if I understand what these differences **really** mean. I suppose that one cannot speak about body count after 9/11 attacks unless s/he speaks about e.g. firemen?